# How do I set a JSDoc tutorial title?

Tags: jsdoc

I'm using JSDoc tutorials, as described in http://usejsdoc.org/about-tutorials.html

I can't get the **configuration** options to work, and I haven't yet found any examples or discussion of the topic online.

In my trivial example, I pass a **tutorials** parameter to JSDoc, and it builds a tutorial file for tutorial1.md. I would like to give this tutorial a display name of "First Tutorial".

Following this from the online docs:

> Each tutorial file can have additional .js/.json file (with same name, just different extension) which will hold additional tutorial configuration. Two fields are supported:
>
> title overrides display name for tutorial with the one specified in it's value (default title for tutorial is it's filename).
>
> children which holds list of sub-tutorials identifiers.

I tried several attempts at adding tutorial1.json, or tutorial1.js but either JSDoc pukes on the json file, or doesn't seem to recognize anything I throw at it in the js file.

Can anyone suggest a simple format for a tutorial configuration file that should work?

(Edited to include one .js file I tried, which did not change the tutorial display name.)

tutorial1.md

```
First Tutorial
================
```

tutorial1.js

```
/**
 @title First Tutorial
 */
@title = "First Tutorial";
title = "First Tutorial";
```

Comment: Please "bore" us with at least one variation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works with `.json` extension but not with a `.js` extension. jsdoc does not seem to try to even *read* the file if a `.js` extension is used. So the [doc](http://usejsdoc.org/about-tutorials.html) seems incorrect.

With a `.json` extension, and using jsdoc 3.2.2, the following works:

```
{
    "title": "Custom Title"
}
```

Your `.json` file needs to be in the same directory as your `.md` file and have the same name (ignoring extensions).