# How to change the title of the generated output of JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc3

I tried to generate a source code documentation of a JavaScript file. For this I also wrote a README using markdown syntax. I run:

```
jsdoc -R client.md -d client client.js
```

The command generates the HTML documentation. In the generated output the following titles are defined:

```
<title>JSDoc: Home</title>
<h1 class="page-title">Home</h1>
```

How can I change `Home` and `JSDoc: Home` to something useful like the name of my program?

I tried already to write a configuration file as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22539334/402322), but that seems to work only for tutorials and not for READMEs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now it is hard coded in the default template. My [pull request](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/pull/1107) makes it configurable. Putting it in the configuration file works with the change.

```
{
  "title": "My title"
}
```

Comment: Great idea with the PR, why does it take 4 years to implement?

Comment: @crs1138 Probably wrong place to ask.

Comment: @ceving actually I want to change `JSDoc` to the actual project name, so that instead of `JSDoc: Home` it could be `My Project: Home` and then other pages will have `My Project: Other` etc. Is that what your PR does? Seems like it only changes the home page title, like `JSDoc: My title` ‍♂️